# Global environment variables in a shell script with Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, sh

I'm trying to create a ENV VAR called SETTINGS in a Python image with Dockerfile. This env var must be dynamic, because I need to change the conf profile betweet production and preproduction.

I've created an script (entrypoint.sh) with two commands, the first one create the SETTINGS VAR and the second one is a python command.

The problem is that the python line works properly but the SETTINGS var doesn't.

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
profile=$profile
export SETTINGS=/acalls-service/${profile}.cfg
python -m "_acalls_clasiffier" 
exec
```

Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". entrypoint.sh"]
```

I've tried with ["./entrypoint.sh] also but I doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share more about what you mean by "the SETTINGS var doesn't"? Can you replace `_acalls_clasiffier` with a hello-world style script, which prints the env var and show us the actual output and what you expect? More information about how you are running and how you are setting the env var would be nice to have too.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a pretty typical use of an entrypoint wrapper script.  Remember that a container only runs a single process.  If your Dockerfile specifies an `ENTRYPOINT`, that's the process, and the `CMD` is passed as additional arguments to it.  That lets you set up a script that does some first-time setup and then replaces itself with the real command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Set the environment variable
export SETTINGS=/acalls-service/${profile}.cfg

# Run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile you'd specify this script as the `ENTRYPOINT` and then the actual command as `CMD`.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]             # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["python", "-m", "_acalls_clasiffier"] # shell syntax allowed here too
```

Since you can easily provide a replacement `CMD`, you can check that this is working

```sh
docker run --rm myimage \
  sh -c 'echo $SETTINGS'  # <-- run in the container, single-quoted so the
                          #     host shell doesn't expand it
```

If you get a debugging shell in the container with `docker exec`, it won't see the variable set because it doesn't run through the entrypoint sequence.  That's not usually a practical problem.  You can always `docker run` a new container with an interactive shell instead of the Python script.

Comment: Same problem. Python command works fine but the SETTINGS var is not created

Comment: Why do you think that?  For example, if your Python script looks at `os.environ['SETTINGS']`, I'd expect it to be set correctly.

Comment: If I use the "set" or echo $SETTINGS command in the python cli the SETTINGS var doesn't appear like the other env vars

Comment: How are you getting a "python CLI"; the `CMD` here should launch a specific program?  As I noted in the last paragraph, the variable won't be visible in the unusual event you need to use `docker exec` to debug the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in passing a `dynamic` environment var on `docker build` or pass the variable on runtime.

## Env vars on runtime

If you want to pass it on runtime, it doesn't need to be in your Dockerfile, just pass it when running your container:

```
docker run my-image -e MY_ENV=foo
```

## Env vars on build

During build you have to:

- define your env var in your Dockerfile
- pass the env var into the build process

Example Dockerfile:

```
  ARG MY_BUILD_ARG=myDefaultArgument

  FROM node:16.9.0

  ARG MY_BUILD_ARG

  ENV MY_PUBLIC_ENV=${MY_BUILD_ARG}

  RUN echo ${MY_PUBLIC_ENV} // => myRandomEnvVar
```

And then pass it when you build as:

```
docker build --build-arg MY_BUILD_ARG=myRandomEnvVar
```